# c++ boost library Entry point could not be located

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, dll

I have a c++ Lib project StoreLib, and I have UnitTest Project where I wrote a unit test to test a functionality of class in StoreLib. StoreLibuses bunch of external dlls

My boostTest project compiles and when I run the exe, it complained about missing bunch of dlls, I pasted all of them in my bin folder. Then get this weird error

**Store.UnitTests.exe - Entry Point Not Found.

The procedure entry point  could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\UnitTest\UnitTests.exe.**

First I am unable to understand why is it treating an exe file (UnitTest.exe) as a dynamic link library ? if I write a simple test i.e. Boost_Check(6==6) with out referring to any header file in my StoreLib it works just fine, though moment I refer to any header file from StoreLib it gives above mentioned error.

Any clue what I am doing wrong ? any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

it turned out that the one the external dll included was old, perhaps it was not finding proer entry point